# What's causing Apache to route this URL?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04

I've inherited a legacy PHP project. Hooray. It's running on a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 14.04, to which I have root access.

It appears to have been built with CodeIgniter. The project consists of a website, a RESTful API, a MySQL database, and PHPMyAdmin.

I'm attempting to clone this production instance onto another droplet so I can make a test environment. So far, I've set up PHPMyAdmin, the website, and the database just fine.

But for the life of me I can't figure out how the routing for this API works.

On the production site, the API is at `productionsite.com/API` (note the capital letters). CodeIgniter's `controller` folder contains all the routes for the API, and it appears to be set up properly. What I can't find is **how to make `testsite.com/API` not just throw a 404**.

- I copied the entire contents of `var/www` from one droplet to another, so presumably if the router was in there, it's now on the test site as well
- I looked everywhere I could think of in `etc`, including `etc/apache2`. I even ran `sudo grep -Ri "API" *` inside `etc` with no avail.
- I checked the DNS records, and nothing routes directly to `/API`

Is there any other place I could look?

Comment: Did you check .htaccess? Maybe on your testing server `rewrite` is not enabled and it doesn't work.

Comment: `.htaccess` is inside the `var/www` folder, so it was included when I copied everything. That said, I checked anyway and didn't find anything.

Comment: Yes, but you can have disabled rewrite module in Apache and if there is an rule in your .htaccess it won't work. That's why I suggested to check .htaccess.

Comment: Ahhh! I'll check.

Comment: Unfortunately I can see `mod_rewrite` in the `Loaded Modules` portion of the `apache2handler` section in both sites' `phpinfo`.

Comment: And what about `.htaccess`? Anything about `API`?